# usage of android native library(.so)

Tags: android, loadlibrary

I have a question regarding android application programming.

Q1. can I make a game with *.so file? and just let android part 
load the so file?

Q2. what happens to the system when I load the so file in android app?

```
System.loadLibrary("mylib");
```

is there an initializing function like DLLMain in windows?
or just the library is loaded and nothing happens before
android part calls it?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, using appropriate toolchain(s).  See the NDK documentation and examples.

2) The runtime linker maps the library into memory and takes steps to make functions in the file available to the process which has requested to load the file.

There are several possible auto-run initializers, both those which would be invoked by the Android runtime linker in the general case (not sure of references other than its source code), and also an additional one that will be called by the DVM if you are specifically loading a JNI library:

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
```

For more information see this page from the NDK:

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html